# _tWinMain in static lib LNK2019

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, static-libraries, winmain

I try put main(WinMain) in static library:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {...}
```

but I got:

```
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

I tried to build as "Unicode", and as "Multi-byte".

I tried write without "_t" (and LPSTR).

I tried write extern "C".

Linker flags include `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` and my static lib

I know that it's possible, because it's done in libraries like SDL, SFML, etc.

Comment: you need to declare it as `extern "C"`. i don't know if that's sufficient but it's necessary (from inspection of the mangled name). if you want your library to support Unicode compile as Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the function in the lib is called _**tWinMain**.

Just call it **WinMain** and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks! Now (`extern "C" int APIENTRY WinMain`) compile both "Unicode", and "Multi-byte" mode.